# Write unit test for a controller that uses AuthComponent in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, authentication

I am trying to test a controller action that allows edition of user profiles. Among other things I want to test that every logged user can only edit its own profile and not other's. In case of breaking this restriction the action must redirect to a predefined home page.

With this scenario, I have a fixture that creates a user with ID = 1. So I was thinking on testing the restriction this way:

```
$data = $this->Users->User->read(null, 1); 
$this->Users->Auth->login($data); 
$this->testAction('/users/edit/2', array('method' => 'get')); 
$url = parse_url($this->headers['Location']); 
$this->assertEquals($url['path'], '/homepage');
```

The test passes this assert. So the next step is to check if executing `'/users/edit/1'`, which has the ID of the logged user, shows the form:

```
$this->testAction('/users/edit/1', array('method' => 'get', 'return' => 'vars'));
$matcher = array( 
  'tag' => 'form', 
  'ancestor' => array('tag' => 'div'), 
  'descendant' => array('tag' => 'fieldset'), 
); 
$this->assertTag($matcher, $this->vars['content_for_layout'], 'The edition form was not found');
```

However this assert fails. After digging around with `debug()` I've found that `$this->Auth->user()` returns the whole information but `$this->Auth->user('id')` returns `null`. Since I use the latter in a comparison within the action, it evaluates as false and causes the 
test to fail.

The curious thing is that it happens when testing but not when executing the action in a browser. So, what's the correct way of testing this action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual correct answer should be using mock objects instead of actually login the user in manually:

```
$this->controller = $this->generate('Users', array(
    'components' => array('Auth' => array('user')) //We mock the Auth Component here
));
$this->controller->Auth->staticExpects($this->once())->method('user') //The method user()
    ->with('id') //Will be called with first param 'id'
    ->will($this->returnValue(2)) //And will return something for me
$this->testAction('/users/edit/2', array('method' => 'get'));
```

Using mocks is the most easy way to test a controller, and also the most flexible one

**Update 11 March 2015**

You can also mock all method of AuthComponent

```
$this->controller = $this->generate('Users', array(
    'components' => array('Auth') // Mock all Auth methods
));
```

Comment: What's the point then of using `ControllerTestCase` if you have to use `generate()` anyway?

Comment: generate() is only available in ControllerTestCase and it is provided in order to make your testAction() easier, such as being able to mock controller methods, componentes, models etc. If you do not call generate() yourself, then testAction() will do it internally for you with the CakePHP defaults (mocking the _stop() and the redirect() function)

Comment: I thought `generate()` actually did something else. That's why I kept thinking why using it if `ControllerTestCase` provided me with a default configuration. I'll try your answer and let you know :)

Comment: Anyway, do you have any reason about why manually login a user is not correct? I mean, I'm testing with dummy data and there should not be any risks...

Comment: Yeah, saving time! both programming time and execution time, mocks when you start to have lots of tests cases to run, the number of calls to the database will quickly slow down your executions. Keeping them and the minimum when not needed is key. Also this does not apply only to the AuthComponent, think of any other component such as Cookie, or Security! How would you fake the data and environment for those two? The quick answer is always mock objects.

Comment: Your answer almost fixed my problem, but I am dealing with some issues still. I have opened a question in Google Groups. Check it out if you are interested: http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/79608ed9b7f9b7df

Comment: This solution didn't work for me either. It turns out that since `Auth->user()` is actually a static method, you need to use `staticExpects()` instead. See this [comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cake-php/eWCO2bf5t98/pYCkv3Fu7IAJ) in the Google Groups thread elitalon linked.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Jose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258924), but when faced with a similar situation I want to use the actual AuthComponent and Session to create a test that would give me confidence.

I am using Controller-based authentication, which means that each controller in my app must provide its own [isAuthorized()](http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentisAuthorized) callback.  I want to test MyController::isAuthorized().  It seems too easy to get a test to pass using mocks.

So ,instead of using TestCase::generate() to create a mock controller with mock components, I followed Mark Story's excellent article [Testing CakePHP Controllers the hard way](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/testing-cakephp-controllers-the-hard-way) and provided my own mock controller that logs in a user with the the real CakePHP AuthComponent.

Here's [my work](https://gist.github.com/3304880).  See the method testIsAuthorized() and the class def for MockAnnouncementsController near the top.

It seems to me that CakePHP testing framework assumes that you want to test controllers only through requestAction().  It was not designed to facilitate direct unit-testing of callback implementations like Controller::isAuthorized() within a controller without mocking the AuthComponent and perhaps other components, and that would give me less confidence in test of that particular method.  Nevertheless, I think this is a valid use-case for unit-testing parts of a controller that are not actions (e.g. "index", "view"), but cannot be delegated to a component because they must be called by the core framework.  I'm still thinking about how I could abstract it to make it available for any controller.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$this->Auth->user('id')
```

Try one of these:

```
$this->Auth->data['User']['id']
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')
```

Comment: It does not work either. Are not these methods meant to be equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Set it like so:

```
$this->Users->Session->write('Auth.User', 
    array('id' => 1,'and_other_fields_you_need' => 'whatever')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark Story gives me the [answer in a CakePHP ticket](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2280-using-key-values-in-this-auth-user-method-does-not-work-while-testing#ticket-2280-4). Basically I have to log the user like this:

```
$data = $this->Users->User->read(null, 1); 
$this->Users->Auth->login($data['User']);
```

instead of

```
$data = $this->Users->User->read(null, 1); 
$this->Users->Auth->login($data);
```